# Where does the human need for intimacy stem from?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, psychology, positive-psychology, health-psychology

I'm reading "The Art of Happiness" right now, and in it, it's written that our need from intimacy stems a fear that developed at childbirth. According to the text, there's much evidence that this fear develops at the 1-year mark, when separation from one's father and mother becomes apparent. The book goes further to state that the root of all suffering in humanity is due to an innate fear of re-experiencing this separated-ness. This by the way, can be found on page 79/235 in the section of "the art of happiness" entitled "expanding our definition of intimacy".

If this true, then are we all Obsessive-Compulsive and just reliving the same scenarios over and over in our lives?

Comment: We are, but not solely for that reason. Ego is the reason.

Comment: Please explain. What would Ego have to do with this question?

Comment: "Ego" means: *everything that we believe about ourselves, without sufficient evidence.* Ego thinks that it is real, when it is not. So, about 99% of what we study or talk about psychologically, is ego. And it is all of it false.

Comment: So that makes sense. So you're saying that another reason for the above behaviour is due to preconceived notions about the self and possibly others. Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. You could also look in to Nonduality, and Non-Symbolic Consciousness.